# GRUB install to wrong partition has broken Windows startup

Tags: 11.04, windows, partitioning, grub2, dual-boot

While installing Ubuntu 11.04 there was an option to choose where GRUB should be installed. The options were each partition or the entire drive. I accidentally chose a Windows partition and now I it no longer boots.

What should have GRUB's location been?

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: When I choose Windows from the GRUB the computer just restarts itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the MBR (master boot record). That's the default choice, and it's the only choice that makes sense in >99% of installations.

If your system can't boot now, insert the installation CD/USB and [repair the bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Then you'll need to repair the Windows bootloader (the bit at the beginning of the Windows partition) as well. On older versions, the command to run was `sys c:`; I don't know if that's still true.